# Mule 3.6.1 xpath3

Tags: mule, xpath-3.0

I am trying to migrate my Mule 3.4 CE applications to Mule 3.6.1 CE and having issues with xpath3.

Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:itemMessage xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/messages">
    <requestId>QAREQ:150623_0002</requestId>
    <requestStatus>COMPLETE</requestStatus>
</ns2:itemMessage>
```

xpath expression (working)

```
#[xpath('string(//itemMessage/requestId/text())')]
```

xpath3 expression (not working)

```
#[xpath3('//itemMessage/requestId/text()', payload, 'STRING')]
```

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Your xpath expressions does not match the XML at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xpath expression does not seem to match the XML document. But based on the XML document this works:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager
        includeConfigNamespaces="true">
   <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns2" uri="http://test.com/messages" />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>

<flow name="testFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <set-payload
            value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt; &lt;ns2:itemMessage xmlns:ns2=&quot;http://test.com/messages&quot;&gt; &lt;requestId&gt;QAREQ:150623_0002&lt;/requestId&gt; &lt;requestStatus&gt;COMPLETE&lt;/requestStatus&gt; &lt;/ns2:itemMessage&gt;"
            doc:name="Set Payload" />
    </poll>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath3('ns2:itemMessage/requestId/text()', payload, 'STRING')]" />
</flow>
```

Comment: I get this error..                                                                                                                                           ERROR 2015-06-25 11:02:23,778 [[testprj].testFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "xpath3('ns2:itemMessage/requestId/text()', payload, 'STRING')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Prefix ns2 has not been declared (net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException)
  net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser:263 (null)

Comment: I was trying in Mule 3.6.1 CE

Comment: This worked when I added the namespace manager. <mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns2" uri="http://test.com/messages"/>
 </mulexml:namespace-manager>

Comment: Yes you need to add the namespace manager. Updated my answer.